# Awaiting a asyncio Future after Cancelling it

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, future

Looking at the [asyncio docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Task.cancel), I came across this example

```
async def main():
    # Create a "cancel_me" Task
    task = asyncio.create_task(cancel_me())

    # Wait for 1 second
    await asyncio.sleep(1)

    task.cancel()
    try:
        await task
    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        print("main(): cancel_me is cancelled now")

asyncio.run(main())
```

After `task.cancel()`, what is the purpose of doing `await task`? Is this to wait for the future to be finished if it was ever shielded from cancellation?

In other words, why not:

```
async def main():
    # Create a "cancel_me" Task
    task = asyncio.create_task(cancel_me())

    # Wait for 1 second
    await asyncio.sleep(1)

    task.cancel()

asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: The point is that the task is already cancelled and can't be awaited anymore. The example code will print the error. Shielded tasks will keep running but also throw CancelledError.

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation of `cancel()` (under [`asyncio.Task`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#task-object)):

> This arranges for a `CancelledError` exception to be thrown into the wrapped coroutine on the next cycle of the event loop.
>
> The coroutine then has a chance to clean up or even deny the request by suppressing the exception with a `try` … … `except CancelledError` … `finally` block.

When `asyncio.CancelledError` is thrown into `cancel_me()`, execution resumes in the `except asyncio.CancelledError` block. For the snippet provided with the documentation, it does not in fact make any difference whether `cancel_me()` is awaited or not after cancelling, because the exception handling block executes synchronously.

On the other hand, if the exception handling block did perform asynchronous operations, the difference would become visible:

```
async def cancel_me():
    print('cancel_me(): before sleep')

    try:
        # Wait for 1 hour
        await asyncio.sleep(3600)
    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        print('cancel_me(): cancel sleep, this never gets printed')
        raise
    finally:
        print('cancel_me(): after sleep')

async def main():
    # Create a "cancel_me" Task
    task = asyncio.create_task(cancel_me())

    # Wait for 1 second
    await asyncio.sleep(1)

    task.cancel()
    print("main(): cancel_me is cancelled now")

asyncio.run(main())

# Expected output:
#
#     cancel_me(): before sleep
#     main(): cancel_me is cancelled now
#     cancel_me(): after sleep
```

The last, surprising print takes place because of the following:

- `main()` returns after its last print
- `asyncio.run()` tries to cancel all pending tasks
- `cancel_me()`, albeit already cancelled, is still pending, awaiting on the exception block sleep
- the `finally` clause in `cancel_me()` is executed and the even loop terminates

Also worth noting: given that `asyncio.run()` throws a `CancelledError` into all the tasks that are still pending, if `cancel_me()` had not been cancelled already, the `except asyncio.CancelledError` block would execute in its entirety.